# Why NameError here

Tags: python-3.x

Why I am getting this error, actually I have already defined ' a' before using in both codes.

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
kwargs={'a':3,'b':5,'c':add(a,b)}
print("a is {a},b is {b}".format(**kwargs))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\GitRepo\Advanced_Python\logNew.py", line 13, in <module>
    kwargs={'a':3,'b':5,'c':add(a,b)}
NameError: name 'a' is not defined


import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
logging.info("Summation of {a},{b} is {c}".format(a=3,b=4,c=add(a,b)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\GitRepo\Advanced_Python\logNew.py", line 5, in <module>
    logging.info("Summation of {a},{b} is {c}".format(a=3,b=4,c=add(a,b)))
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: `kwargs={'a':3,'b':5,'c':add(a,b)}`, that a and b should be defined outside the kwargs dictionary itself, somewhere above

Comment: You did not define a variable `a`; you assigned a value to the key `'a'` in the dictionary currently under construction.

Comment: There is no way in a `dict` literal to refer to the keys assigned "earlier" in the same literal.

Answer (score 1):

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
kwargs={'a':3,'b':5}
kwargs['c']=add(kwargs['a'],kwargs['b'])

print("a is {a},b is {b}".format(**kwargs))
```

you have to write like this , a is not variable here, it is constant 'a'.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

a=3
b=4
logging.info("Summation of {a},{b} is {c}".format(a=a,b=b,c=add(a,b)))
```

you have to declare variables first then use it.

Answer (score 0):

When the python interpreter encounters the line: `kwargs={'a':3,'b':5,'c':add(a,b)}`. This is what it does:

1. Evaluate all the values of the keys being assigned to
2. This includes `3`, `5` and `add(a, b)`
3. 3 & 5 get defined as usual - since those are constants
4. `add(a, b)` - here `add` is defined (the function you defined above)
5. But `a` or `b` are not defined!

Hence the error. `a` & `b` are not variables (you can check this by checking the `locals()` & `globals()` - variables should show up there). They are keys in the dictionary.

This will work:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
a = 3
b = 5
kwargs={'a':a,'b':b,'c':add(a,b)}
print("a is {a},b is {b}".format(**kwargs))
```

Because the variables `a` & `b` are defined before `add(a, b)` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Your "add" function is expecting two integers, but you are not giving it when in dictionary expression. Look:

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
kwargs={'a':3,'b':5,'c':add(5,2)}
print("a is {a},b is {b}".format(**kwargs))
```

I am passing 5 and 2 in dictionary expression.

Hope this helps.